# CSS to create full-page no-margin solid color background in print

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing, chromium

I am trying to set a solid background color for the entire printed page when printing from Chrome. The content to be on the page is a dynamic list of unknown length that might span multiple pages.

In order to remove the white margins, I set the margins to 0 mm using the @page rule.

There are two issues that I have not found a solution to.

1. Unable to set top margin for content on subsequent pages
2. Unable to fill the last page to the bottom with solid color

What I got:

```
<html>    
<head>
    <style>
    @page {  
        margin: 0mm; }
    html {    
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;    
        background-color: coral;     
        font-size: 150%; }
    h1 {
        padding-top: 50mm;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Items</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum dolor</li><li>Sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum dolor</li><li>Sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum dolor</li><li>Sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum dolor</li><li>Sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum dolor</li><li>Sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum dolor</li><li>Sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum dolor</li><li>Sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum dolor</li><li>Sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum dolor</li><li>Sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum dolor</li><li>Sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum dolor</li><li>Sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum dolor</li><li>Sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum dolor</li><li>Sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum dolor</li><li>Sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum dolor</li><li>Sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum dolor</li><li>Sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum dolor</li><li>Sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum dolor</li><li>Sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum dolor</li><li>Sit amet</li>
        <li>Lorem</li><li>Ipsum dolor</li><li>Sit amet</li>
    </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Print rendering in Chrome (from saved pdf):
[image]

Comment: Top margin can be set if you switch to using table for layout (yay) and [use the thead tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274149/repeat-table-headers-in-print-mode) to create a top margin for every page

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting but only gets me half there. Since I asked the question I have solved the issue by setting the background color using the itext pdf library (which I already use in the project).

Comment: Have you tried adding `html, body {margin: 0; }` to reset the default browser margins and `html { min-height: 100vh; }` to extend the html document to the full viewport width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently experiencing the same issue as you. I have found a solution for the 2nd part as you can read here:

[Have margins for content but not background on every page when converting/printing HTML to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70078935/have-margins-for-content-but-not-background-on-every-page-when-converting-html-t)

and here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70079034/1222240

you have to create a div with position: fixed and then width and height as 100%, set z-index to 0 and then you can change the background color, it will be printed on every page

The container div will need to have position: relative and z-index: 1

For the first issue I solved in puppeteer (which I'm using to create a pdf version of the page by having it "printed" by google under the hood) by using the header and footer attributes of the library [Have margins for content but not background on every page when converting/printing HTML to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70078935/have-margins-for-content-but-not-background-on-every-page-when-converting-printi/70098981#70098981)