# Different background image for first and other pages of sections in printed document

Tags: html, css, printing

I want to have an HTML document consiting of several sections which could be printed into pdf. For example:

```
<body>

    <div class="section">
        <p class="text">There is supposed to be lots of text (section 1)</p>
        <figure class="picture">
            <img src="cat.jpg" alt="Cat">
            <figcaption>Picture 1 - Cat</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p class="text">Also lots of text (section 1)</p>
    </div>

    <div class="section">
        <p class="text">There is supposed to be lots of text (section 2)</p>
        <figure class="picture">
            <img src="cat.jpg" alt="Cat">
            <figcaption>Picture 1 - Cat</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p class="text">Also lots of text (section 2)</p>
    </div>

</body>
```

```
@page {
  size: A4 portrait;
  margin: 0;
}
.section {
    break-after: page;
}
```

This example would've worked if i hadn't to print some frame images on pages (using background-image). The problem with that is that **first** printed page of section (not the whole document) has to be sourced from "bigframe.gif" and all other pages of **this section** has to be "smallframe.gif".

So when another section starts, first printed page of another section should be "bigrame.gif" and so on.

How can i achieve this using CSS or php?

I tried to solve my problem using solution here: [How to use HTML to print header and footer on every printed page of a document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360869/how-to-use-html-to-print-header-and-footer-on-every-printed-page-of-a-document). But it can only print on all pages, it's not suitable for my case.

This: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70079034/15146417 is promising but it has no support of sections